Role of a women/wife in working
I was having discussion over roles of wives and someone told me that Hazrat Khadija was successful business women but she use to work from home, because Allah has said for women to stay within bounds of the house, is it true that she use to run her business from home?

Khadijah engaged in business before the advent of Islam and had already died in the Meccan period before the revelation of the rules of Hijab. Anyways she participated in Mudarabah which means she contributed capital and her business partner would carry out the trade activities using that investment. She also had a slave who participated in that - she did not go out of her house to work. See Position of Muhammad (PBUH) under Khadija

Hazrat Khadijah PBUH was a rich and succesfull trader, but had people to do the trades for her. But this doesn't mean women should stay at homes. Yes, its generally safer for them and the rest of the society for them to remain at home, as long as there is no requirement for the otherwise (and this is almost the same suggestion for men according to Imam Sadiq PBUH, while requirement for men to appear in the society happens/or used to happen so much more frequently). For example it is generally advised that woman study in the fields which mainly concern about women/children. An Obstetricians is certainly preferred to be a woman. A teacher specifically for younger children is suggested to be a woman. So not a strict rule for woman to remain at home, but only a suggestion. We should all remember that being a mother/wife is not an easy role, and should be appraised so that no woman would feel being a mother is equal to be forgotten/put aside from the society, or the stream of living a beneficial/useful life.
